# InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. (0) Invalid argument: indices[10,0] = 101102 is not in [0, 101102)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recommendation-engine

I am trying to create a movie recommendation system by training the neural collaborative filtering (NCF) network on the MovieLens dataset. My implementation of NCF is

```
def NCF(num_users, num_items, gmf_embedding_dim, mlp_embedding_dim):
    # Define input vectors for embedding
    u_input = Input(shape = [1,])
    i_input = Input(shape = [1,])

    # GMF embedding
    u_embedding_gmf = Embedding(input_dim = num_users, output_dim = gmf_embedding_dim(u_input)
    u_vec_gmf = Flatten()(u_embedding_gmf)

    i_embedding_gmf = Embedding(input_dim = num_items, output_dim = gmf_embedding_dim(i_input)
    i_vec_gmf = Flatten()(i_embedding_gmf)

    # MLP embedding
    u_embedding_mlp = Embedding(input_dim = num_users, output_dim = mlp_embedding_dim(u_input)
    u_vec_mlp = Flatten()(u_embedding_mlp)

    i_embedding_mlp = Embedding(input_dim = num_items, output_dim = mlp_embedding_dim(i_input)
    i_vec_mlp = Flatten()(i_embedding_mlp)

    # GMF path
    gmf_output = Dot(axes = 1)([u_vec_gmf, i_vec_gmf])

    # MLP path
    mlp_input_concat = Concatenate()([u_vec_mlp, i_vec_mlp])

    mlp_dense_1 = Dense(units = 128, activation = "relu")(mlp_input_concat)
    mlp_bn_1 = BatchNormalization()(mlp_dense_1)
    mlp_drop_1 = Dropout(0.3)(mlp_bn_1)

    mlp_dense_2 = Dense(units = 64, activation = "relu")(mlp_drop_1)
    mlp_bn_2 = BatchNormalization()(mlp_dense_2)
    mlp_output = Dropout(0.3)(mlp_bn_2)

    # Concatenate GMF and MLP pathways
    paths_concat = Concatenate()([gmf_output, mlp_output])

    # Prediction
    output = Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")(paths_concat)

    # Create model 

    return Model(inputs = [u_input, i_input], outputs = output)
```

I created a function to handle my training

```
def train(model, x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, batch_size, epochs, save_name,
         checkpoint_path, history_path, lr = 0.001, lr_decay = True):

    if isfile(join(history_path, save_name)):
        return

    model.compile(loss = BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = lr), 
                 metrics["accuracy"])

    best_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = join(checkpoint_path, save_name),
                                     monitor = "val_loss",
                                     save_best_only = True)

    history_csv = CSVLogger(join(history_path, save_name))

    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss",
                              patience = 30,
                              restore_best_weights = True)

    lr_decay_callback = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = "val_loss",
                                 patience = 10,
                                 factor = 0.5,
                                 min_lr = 0.000001)

    callback_list = [best_checkpoint, history_csv, early_stop]

    if lr_decay:
        callback_list.append(lr_decay_callback)
    
    model.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train, validation_data = (x_valid, y_valid),
           epochs = epochs, callbacks = callback_list, batch_size = batch_size)
```

Encoded the user_ID and movie_ID values ready for the embedding layers with

```
enc = LabelEncoder()
train_set["user_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(train_set["user_ID"].values)
enc = LabelEncoder()
train_set["movie_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(train_set["movie_ID"].values)

enc = LabelEncoder()
valid_set["user_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(valid_set["user_ID"].values)
enc = LabelEncoder()
valid_set["movie_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(valid_set["movie_ID"].values)

enc = LabelEncoder()
test_set["user_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(test_set["user_ID"].values)
enc = LabelEncoder()
test_set["movie_ID"] = enc.fit_transform(test_set["movie_ID"].values)
```

Then initiated the training with

```
train(model = NCF(num_users = train_set["user_ID"].nunique() + 1, num_items = 
     train_set["movie_ID"].nunique() + 1, gmf_embedding_dim = 10, mlp_embedding_dim = 10),
     x_train = [train_set["user_ID"], train_set["movie_ID"]], y_train =
     train_set["interaction"],
     x_valid = [valid_set["user_ID"], valid_set["movie_ID"]], y_valid = 
     valid_set["interaction"],
     batch_size = (train_set.shape[0])/10, epochs = 50, save_name = "NCF_1",
     checkpoint_path = "D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/model data/checkpoints",
     history_path = "D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/model data/training history")
```

The training appeared to go fine until the very last batch of the first epoch, where I received the error:

**InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.**

**(0) Invalid argument:  indices[10,0] = 101102 is not in [0, 101102)
[[node functional_9/embedding_16/embedding_lookup (defined at D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/architecture and training\training_and_evaluation.py:38) ]]
[[functional_9/embedding_18/embedding_lookup/_16]]**

**(1) Invalid argument:  indices[10,0] = 101102 is not in [0, 101102)
[[node functional_9/embedding_16/embedding_lookup (defined at D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/architecture and training\training_and_evaluation.py:38) ]]**

**0 successful operations.**

**0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_529078]**

This was a very similar error to that which I received at the end of my previous attempt, where the value was 101101 instead of 101102. As a naive solution, I tried adding 1 to my values for num_users and num_movies, but now the values in the error message appear to have simply increased by 1. I feel like I am missing something obvious or fundamental about embedding layers here. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error occurred  as a result of the embedding layer encountering a value that it did not expect. When you are calling the `NCF` function you are passing the unique number of users of the train set. Instead calculate the unique number of users in the full data set and send it to the `NCF` function.

For example:

```
total_num_users = train_set["user_ID"].nunique() + valid_set["user_ID"].nunique() + test_set["user_ID"]..]nunique()

train(model = NCF(num_users = total_num_users, num_items = 
     train_set["movie_ID"].nunique() + 1, gmf_embedding_dim = 10, mlp_embedding_dim = 10),
     x_train = [train_set["user_ID"], train_set["movie_ID"]], y_train =
     train_set["interaction"],
     x_valid = [valid_set["user_ID"], valid_set["movie_ID"]], y_valid = 
     valid_set["interaction"],
     batch_size = (train_set.shape[0])/10, epochs = 50, save_name = "NCF_1",
     checkpoint_path = "D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/model data/checkpoints",
     history_path = "D:/Movie Recommendation System Project/model data/training history")
```

Make sure to follow the same approach to other categorical variables that you are embedding.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I decided to create a temporary set where I appended the validation and test sets to the training set, and then used the number of unique user IDs as the input vector size for user embeddings. I found that this somewhat reduced the training time.